# AsyncContext response does not match original incoming request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

We have a web application with a dashboard that is continuously polling for updates. On the server-side, the request for updates is made asynchronous so that we can respond when an update occurs through a listener/notify system.

**The problem** we're seeing is that when one of these polling requests is being responded to, it can in some cases write to the request/response for a *user-clicked link.*

The incoming request for the async update looks like:

```
@RequestMapping("/getDashboardStatus.json")
public void getDashboardStatus(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
    final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
    // 10 seconds
    asyncContext.setTimeout(10000);
    asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // .. (code here waits for an update to occur) ..
            sendMostRecentDashboardJSONToResponse(asyncContext.getResponse());
            if (asyncContext.getRequest().isAsyncStarted()) {
                asyncContext.complete();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What's *strange*, is that there are links on this dashboard that go to other pages. Every ~100 clicks or so, one of them will *instead of displaying the chosen page*, actually display the JSON sent above!

For example, we have a separate MVC method:

```
@RequestMapping("/result/{resultId}")
public ModelAndView getResult(@PathVariable String resultId) {
    return new ModelAndView(...);
}
```

And when clicking on a link on the dashboard that visits `/result/1234`, every blue moon, the page will load with a 200 OK status, but instead of containing the expected HTML, actually contains the JSON for the polling request!

Is only one request per client allowed? Does a request initiated by a clicked link *override* any async requests that are already sitting on the server-side from the same client?

How can we manage these requests to ensure that the async response goes to the *async* request?

I noticed a `hasOriginalRequestAndResponse()` method on the `AsyncContext` object, but am having difficulty understanding from the Javadoc whether it's what I'm looking for.

**Update:** I just added a snippet like so:

```
String requestURI = ((HttpServletRequest)asyncContext.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
System.out.println("Responding w/ Dashboard to: " + requestURI);
sendMostRecentDashboardJSONToResponse(asyncContext.getResponse(), clientProfileKey);
```

And was able to reproduce the issue, during *proper* behavior, I see:

```
Responding w/ Dashboard to: /app/getDashboardStatus.json
```

But when I see JSON pushed to the click-initiated requests, I see:

```
Responding w/ Dashboard to: null
```

Comment: There is an ongoing meta discussion about the tags used in this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281443/how-general-must-a-problem-be-to-warrant-use-of-a-language-library-tag

Comment: @Craig Otis Did you try to use the `request.startAsync(request, response);` instead of `request.startAsync()`?

Comment: @fmodos I read the docs for it, but didn't actually use it - it doesn't seem like the behavior would change in this scenario? It seems the request/response arguments passed in to that method would need to be the same (or wrappers) of the incoming request/responses, so it seems that it would operate the same.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25626998/31158) might be related.

Comment: @CraigOtis I think that in your scenario the async context is getting lost with the actual attached response. I agree with you about the javadoc and also expect that internally when start the async of one request `startAsync()`, it keeps the response attached to that request... but maybe it worth a try for testing purpose :)

Comment: @Jordão It seems *related*, but doesn't seem to explain the issue here, as that snippet states that when `startAsync()` has been called on the request, it is not eligible for recycling until `complete()` has been called on the context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured this one out. The request/responses *are* indeed being recycled, so by hanging on to the response assigned to the `AsyncContext`, I was writing out to a response that was associated with a *different* request.

Calling `startAsync()` guarantees that the request/response objects will not be recycled until the asynchronous context has been completed. Despite my finding no place where the context would be completed prematurely or erroneously, it *was* being completed:

**By the timeout.**

I was able to consistently reproduce this issue by waiting for 10+ seconds with no server-side activity, allowing the JSON update request to timeout, and *then* clicking on a link. After the timeout, the request/response associated with the asynchronous context is timed out, and thus *completed*, and thus **recycled**.

There were two **solutions** that I discovered.

The *first* is to add an `AsyncListener` to the context, and keep track of whether or not the timeout had occurred. When your listener detects a timeout, you flip a `boolean`, and check it before writing to the response.

The *second* is to simply call `isAsyncStarted()` on the request prior to writing to the response. If the context has timed out, this method will return `false`. If the context is still valid/waiting, it will return `true`.

Comment: The second solution can occasionaly fail, because there is a race between the processing thread and timeout handling thread, so it is possible that timeout will happen between the call to isAsyncStarted and following write. The solution with timeout listener must also apply a mutual exclusion between the timeout listener and write to avoid the same problem.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to drop a boolean. I'm using Tomact 9.0.3+, I can no more get the request or the response because it throws an illegal state exception. Is there any other way to drop a boolean flag than reading in a different thread of the one that triggered the timeout?
Does testing on isAsyncStarted return false only in the case of timeout?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Asynchronous Request Processing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async) chapter in the Spring reference docs, you will notice that you can simplify your solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDashboardStatus.json", 
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Callable<MostRecentDashboard> getDashboardStatus() {
    return new Callable() {
        @Override
        public MostRecentDashboard call() {
            // .. (code here waits for an update to occur) ..
            return ...;
        }
    });
}
```

The `MostRecentDashboard` instance will be serialized using Jackson (provided that Jackson 2 is on the classpath).

Next, you need a `TaskExecutor` that will execute the `Callable` (it is also commonly used to configure the default timeout), read the [Spring MVC Async Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async-configuration-spring-mvc) paragraph for options. Alternatively, you can return a `DeferredResult<MostRecentDashboard>` if Spring does not know the thread that assigns the value of the `MostRecentDashboard`, e.g. the `MostRecentDashboard` instances are read from JMS, Redis or similar. For more information, read the [Introducing Servlet 3, Async Support](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support) blog post.

As of [Spring version 4.1](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements), you can return a `ListenableFuture<MostRecentDashboard>` directly from your controller, which is useful if you fetch the `MostRecentDashboard` using a `AsyncRestTemplate`.